# How to throw an error and return an empty list at the same time?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am working on a homework right now and I am asked to return an empty list and print an error message if the field is empty.

This is my code so far, however either the throw error or return empty list (the later one if I change the order) is unreachable. How am I supposed to do that?

```
// the method is not void it returns a list
  if (fileContent.equals(null)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
            throw new Error("ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.");
        } else {
            // return another list ;
}
```

And this is the error that I have been getting:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Console output not as expected in parseFileContent. 
Expected :ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.
Actual   :ERROR: executing parseFileContent for console output check:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asked to **print** the error or do you have to **throw** it?

Comment: If you want to *print* result, then do it *before* throwing the exception. But as for your question title -- how to return a value *and* throw an exception -- you can't; it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you don't need to throw the error, but just have to print it. In that case, do this:

```
if(fileContent.equals(null)) {
    // If you need to print the error:
    System.err.println("ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.");
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;  
} else {
    // return anotherList
}
```